# Interpolating Nested Data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm a relative newcomer to purrr and nested data, and I'm having a problem I don't understand. Basically, I have a series of discontinuous vertical profiles (separated by region and pressure level) that I need to interpolate. The DPUT is below, but I need to interpolate from data that is at 200, 300, 500, 700, and 1000 to data at, for example, `seq(100,1000,100)`.

This seems like a perfect question for `nest()`, so I tried the following:

```
OH_Interp <- as.tibble(Spiv.OH) %>%
  group_by(Month, Region) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(interpolation = modify(data, spline,
                                      xout = seq(100,1000,100))) %>%
  select(Month, Region, interpolation) %>%
  unnest()
```

I expected this to return a 40x4 dataframe mirroring the structure of the input dataframe, with the interpolated data in place of the original data. The `spline()` appears to have worked correctly, but because the `interpolation` structure didn't preserve the structure of `data`, I can't seem to use `unnest()` as I expect - instead, it merely destroy the internal structure of the `interpolation` list and doubles the length of the output to an 8x3 tibble. How can I make it output a 40x4 dataframe instead?

Thank you in advance for your help!

The dataframe in question:

> structure(list(Pressure = c(1000L, 900L, 800L, 700L, 500L, 300L, 
>   200L, 1000L, 900L, 800L, 700L, 500L, 300L, 200L, 1000L, 900L,  800L,
>   700L, 500L, 300L, 200L, 1000L, 900L, 800L, 700L, 500L,  300L, 200L),
>   Value = c(8.12, 11.76, 17.14, 20.5, 21.08, 14.2, 
>   11.2, 7.14, 7.59, 7.98, 8.45, 8.72, 8.94, 8.94, 3.24, 4.12, 4.74, 
>   5.36, 5.34, 4.26, 3.94, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.1, 0.1 ), Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L), .Label =
>   c("January", "July"), class = "factor"), Region = structure(c(2L,  2L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Polar", 
>   "Subtropics"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Pressure", "Value", 
>   "Month", "Region"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L ))

Jared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the spline output to a dataframe/tibble, you can unnest it easily:

```
as.tibble(Spiv.OH) %>%
    group_by(Month, Region) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(interpolation = modify(data, 
                                  function(df, ...) { spline(df, ...) %>% 
                                          as_tibble()
                                  },
                                  xout = seq(100,1000,100))) %>%
    select(Month, Region, interpolation) %>%
    unnest(interpolation)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 40 x 4
   Month   Region         x     y
   <fct>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 January Subtropics   100 10.4 
 2 January Subtropics   200 11.2 
 3 January Subtropics   300 14.2 
 4 January Subtropics   400 18.1 
 5 January Subtropics   500 21.1 
 6 January Subtropics   600 21.9 
 7 January Subtropics   700 20.5 
 8 January Subtropics   800 17.1 
 9 January Subtropics   900 11.8 
10 January Subtropics  1000  8.12
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured it had to be something easy like this.